# How can I find the words from a list with an "i" in the second position? [Python]

Tags: python, list

How can I find the words from a list with an "i" in the second position in Python?

```
example_list = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven']
```

I want to find all words with an "i" in the second position

```
the output should look like this: ['five','six']
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `indexing` to check the condition. `Strings` can also be indexed like `list` like in a string `s = 'python'`, `s[0] is 'p', s[1] is 'y'`

```py
[i for i in example_list if i[1] == 'i']
```

```
['five', 'six']
```

Comment: What if the word has less than 2 characters?

Comment: IndexError will occur @Thrasi

Comment: @Thrasi the point is I am not handling all cases, there can be a possibility that `example_list` will contain a numeric value. I am supposed to solve the problem what OP is asked. But feedbacks are appreciated.

Comment: While you don't have to handle everything (like type validation), accounting for a list of any length would be *expected* by any robust and useful code.